# Magento "parse error: syntax error" when I try to add or duplicate product

Tags: magento

In Magento backend, when I try to add or duplicate a product, I get this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$validatedPath' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in /home2/osarri/public_html/olasarri.com/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php on line 828

I haven't added products for a couple of weeks, but it worked fine then. Any help?

So far I have truncated all log files in phpMyAdmin and flushed Magento cache. To no avail.

This is around line 828:

```
/**
     * Check 2 variants: $requestPath and $requestPath . '-' . $productId
     */
    $validatedPath = $this->getResource()->checkRequestPaths(
        array($requestPath.$suffix, $requestPath.'-'.$product->getId().$suffix),
        $storeId
    );

    if ($validatedPath) {
        return $validatedPath;
    }
    /**
     * Use unique path generator
     */
    return $this->getUnusedPath($storeId, $requestPath.$suffix, $idPath);
}
```

Comment: Which version of Magento is this?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that, it's 1.8.1.0

Comment: I guess I'm on my own here...